# std::transform needs special care with sets

Tags: c++, stl, stl-algorithm

I don't understand why this snippet of code compiles:

```
#include <set>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

int modify(int i)
{
 return 2*i;
}

int main (int args, char** argv)
{
  std::set<int> a;
  a.insert(1);
  a.insert(2);
  a.insert(3);

  std::list<int> b;  // change to set here

  std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), modify);   // line 19
}
```

while, if I just change the type of b from `std::list<int>` to `std::set<int>` it fails at compilation time (at line 19) with the error: *read-only variable is not assignable*.
To use b as a set I need to change the transform line to

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), std::inserter(b, b.begin()), modify);
```

Why is that? I somehow guess the reason has to do with the fact that set is an associative container, while list is a sequence container, but I might be completely off the point here.

### Edit

I forgot to mention: I tried this on gcc 3.4.2 and llvm 3.3 using the default standard (c++98). I tried again on llvm 3.3 using c++03 and I get the same behavior.

Comment: Look at the type of `std::set::iterator`. However, a list won't work either if it doesn't have any space to put the transformed elements.

Comment: @UndefinedBehavior you've got undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code without `std::inserter`, `transform` assigns to `*b.begin()`. In the case of `set` that's a const reference to an element (since C++11). Hence, a compile-time error.

In the case of the `list` it still assigns to `*b.begin()`, which compiles but has undefined behavior because the list has size 0. So `b.begin()` may not be dereferenced.

You are correct that this is to do with the fact that `set` is an associative container whereas `list` is a sequence. Associative containers don't let you modify the part of the element used as a key. In the case of `set` that part *is* the element, for `map` you can modify the value but not the key.

The whole point of `std::inserter` is to arrange that instead of assigning through an iterator, it calls `insert`.

Answer (score 4):

First, the code as you have it exhibits undefined behavior, since the target list doesn't actually have space. Use a `back_inserter` to create space as you go.

As for the set, a set's elements are immutable. This is why you can't assign to a dereferenced iterator, even if you had space. But using the `inserter` is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

This record

```
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), modify);
```

is invalid even for `std::list<int>` (though it can be compiled for std::list or std::set in C++ 2003 where set has non-const iterator) because you defined an empty list.

```
std::list<int> b;
```

When such a record is used it is supposed that the output container already has elements in the range

```
[b.begin(), b.begin() + distance( a.begin(), a.end() ) )
```

because they are reassigned.
So if to consider a set then it is supposed that the set has already all required elements but you may not change them. When you use iterator adapter std::insert_iterator then it adds new elements in the container. So in this case you may use a set.

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 this code compiles but results in undefined behavior - you cannot simply change values of set because they must be in ascending order. In c++11 that was fixed and `set::iterator` is a bidirectional iterator on `const T`, so you cannot change its values at all. `std::inserter` does not change existing values, instead it inserts new values in `operator++` and so everything works

Comment: For me it doesn't compile also in C++03, at least using llvm 3.3.